# Flow for downloading and unzipping files for Heroku and S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, zip

I'm working with Apple's iTunes EPF data files. I'll daily need to download, unzip and then process 1-3GB of data in .tbz files every day.

I've got a Rails app, hosted on Heroku, with most asset storage being taken care of on S3.

But what I'm having trouble with is the flow for getting the EPF files from Apple.

There are 3 files I'll be downloading. Each are .tbz files varying in size from 1GB to down to ~20MB.

Heroku doesn't have a way to reliable store files, so I assume I need to download the files directly to S3? Then would I somehow unzip them there?

That's where I'm hitting a snag. I know how to actually get the files from Apple and on to S3, but decompressing them is where I'm not following.

And since the data files can be pretty large, minimizing the transfer over S3 is critical to keeping costs down.

Is there a service that can let me download the Apple files to their servers, decompress, and then upload to S3 the necessary files?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's [file system is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), but you can still write out to `/tmp` as a temporary scratch space to download, unzip, do whatever processing you need, re-package (if needed), and then uploaded to S3. Because of [automatic dyno restarts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (or manual restarts), just make sure your service knows how to gracefully resume if interrupted.

Comment: Right...but like I mentioned...I'm not following how to unzip the files. Whether on Heroku or S3.

Comment: You would do that on Heroku. Sounds like you're using Ruby, so something like [rubyzip](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip) would work.